# Combining two or more Unity colliders using Boolean algebra for the physics system

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, physics, collider

I have an object representing an old-fashioned cubic dice. These are approximately cuboidal, but with rounded corners and circular facets. I may need to roll a lot of these, and I don't want any ending up balanced on their corner, so the best way to accomplish this (to my mind) is by combining a Box collider with a Sphere collider.

Normally when you do this in Unity, a collision would be detected when *either* the box *or* the sphere touches something else, but I need it to happen when *both* the box *and* the sphere touch something else. This should be much faster than using a mesh, but I'm not sure how to accomplish it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not just use a mesh collider?

Comment: That's probably what I'll end up having to do, but it seems wasteful. A moderately complex mesh collider for the same shape contains 200 facets. I could reduce it further, but I'd end up with a truncated cube which is annoyingly likely to land on a corner. Compare this with using only two primitive colliders, which would not only be a lot simpler but would also be an exact representation of the physical object.

Comment: `ending up balanced on their corner` .. this is pretty unlikely to happen ... and if it does a sphere won't help you! If the cube is exactly balanced at `45°` then it will also stay there if there is a sphere at its bottom

Comment: @derHugo if I use only the cube, then the dice will visibly roll on thin air; it won't look natural. If I use a mesh approximating the round-cornered cube, it will either have a high number of facets (200) which may slow down the physics system, or it will basically be a cube with the corners cut off into triangles, and that's where it might end up balancing on a corner.

Comment: you could try and use 12 capsule colliders along the edges .. still it can possibly end up on the edge if there is no angular speed and it's exactly on a 45° rotation (just tested ;) )

Comment: @derHugo that's not the shape of die I'm aiming for, but I have considered that as a possibility for other shapes of dice. This is the type I want to simulate: https://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/ASKOKI_loaded_dice.jpg
Due to the nature of the throw, it's never going to have zero angular speed.

Comment: Ah I see ^^ I think I would go for a `MeshCollider` and build a custom reduced mesh (e.g. in blender or whatever) I think the edge case of this being stick on the edge is pretty small ... in order to fully avoid it games often implement some fallback logic .. like if a cube is stuck for X seconds on an edge push it down by force (via code) until it ends up on a certain face, allowing it to either move itself apart from the other objects or push the others away .. in addition you can have similar fallback logic to fix the angle if exactly on edge

Comment: And actually though very unlikely these dices **can** in the real world potentially end up on the corner as well ;) The `MeshCollider` component will anyway reduce your collider mesh down if it has to many faces so you don't even need to do this manually - but it gives you better control if you do

Comment: I expect I won't have much choice. I've managed to get the mesh collider down to 144 facets, but I don't think it will usefully go any lower. Going to make a test-case and see how well it runs. If I have to use eight sphere colliders at the corners it might make a passable solution. I can get pretty close to the right shape that way, though I'm going to need to calculate the positioning of the corners and size of the spheres very carefully.